# RegEx for detecting brackets whose content begins with two possible strings

Tags: javascript, regex, match

I need a regex to detect these two types of string:

```
(+US$[ANYTHING GOES HERE])

(-US$[ANYTHING GOES HERE])
```

So for example, these are valid:

```
(+US$5.50)
(-US$8892323.45)
```

I have found a regex for identifying brackets, and it looks like this, but I'm not sure how to change it so it detects only brackets whose content begins with `"+$US"` or `"-$US"`

```
/\((.*?)\)/
```

Comment: Can brackets (meaning: `[` and `]`) be in the string? Also, will the content inside will always be in the form of these examples? Please take a look at [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/HQaow6/1) and see if it helps you

Comment: after -US$ or +US$ there should be just numbers (and decimal point maybe), but if it's easier for you anything can go after it. It's just important that content in () begins with +US$ or -US$

Comment: Do you want to extract the string inside braces?

Comment: @jrook thank you very much, please make it a answer so I can accept it as solution.

Comment: The current answer  by  @gyre    is very good. If it works for you, please accept that one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [`/^\([+-]US\$\d+(?:\.\d{2})?\)/`](https://regex101.com/r/Be0LYC/2):

```js
console.log([
  '(+US$5.50)', //=> true
  '(-US$8892323.45)', //=> true
  '(+US$5.50) STUFF AFTER MATCH', //=> false
  '-US$8892323.45' //=> false
].map(/ /.test,
  /^\([+-]US\$\d+(?:\.\d{2})?\)$/
))
```

Comment: This matches `(-US$2.)`

Comment: Probably better to force either two decimal places or none at all; I agree. Fixed now :)

Comment: In any case it should work for the OP given the criteria and examples. If in doubt, they can always replace the whole section after the `\$` with a good old `.*`.